# Node.js file system modes?

Tags: node.js, file-io

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around opening and reading from a simple text file in Node.js. Part of my problem is that [many of the file system functions](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) require a mysterious [mode] argument. This is apparently a four digit number that... does something. I have no idea what and I can't seem to find a good explanation. I suspect that this is something rather basic to elite node.js hackers, but I'm finding it rather mystifying. Can anyone explain what this argument does?

Comment: They're unix modes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)

Comment: And [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-chmod-numeric-permissions-notation-command/) is a page explaining the numeric values of those modes.

Comment: @robertklep Is there a good way to compose those programmatically Node.js? Or do I do the arithmetic by hand?

Comment: @deathgaze I don't think that there's an interface for it in Node, but the arithmetic isn't that hard and usually you only use a couple of modes anyway (like '0755' or '0644'). And the `mode` argument is optional because it only makes sense when creating new files, not opening/reading existing files.